# How to restore missing field from feature?

Tags: 7, entities, features

I've not removed any tables from db, but when I was trying to edit user profile I've got error about missing field from profile2 entity:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_my_name.
>   in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo()

Indeed field is missing and db field tables too :/

Field is exported to feature. So I thought this may restore my table:

> drush fr my_feature --force -y

but don't...

I've also noticed that I have a lot of tables like field_deleted_data_[number] in db.

Comment: Probably only restoring tables from backup do the job. Unfortunately :(